# TSQL Get records that don't exist in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, exists, not-exists

I have a table that holds data for employees and results of a questionnaire they took. The questionnaire has 3 questions, but not all questions had to be answered. I am trying to find out what questions were not answered by the employees.

EmployeeData:

```
EmployeeID | Question | Answer
-------------------------------
12345      | 1        | 100
-------------------------------
12345      | 2        | 85
-------------------------------
11111      | 1        | 100
-------------------------------
11111      | 2        | 90
-------------------------------
11111      | 3        | 25
-------------------------------
```

If using the table above, I am trying to write a query that would return:

```
EmployeeID | Question
----------------------
12345      | 3 
----------------------
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a table with the question definitions? It would pretty simple with that.

Comment: @SeanLange I don't have a questions table at this time. It wouldn't take much effort to create one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method for doing this is to create a list of all questions for all employees and then remove the ones that are already answered.

You can do this with subqueries, a `cross join`, and a `left outer join`:

```
select e.*, q.*
from (select distinct employeeid from employeedata) e cross join
     (select distinct question from employeedata) q left join
     employeedata ed
     on ed.employeeid = e.employeeid and ed.question = q.question
where ed.employeeid is null;
```

Comment: That is a great start! Thank you! This query returns me the single question that was not answered, but does not tell me the employee that did not answer that question. Is there a way to get the employee id and question out of your query?

Comment: @btjordan23: Replace `select ed.*, q.*` with `select e.*, q.*`

Answer (score 2):

First you need a list of the employees.  A better source would be the employee table if it exists.  What if an employee didn't fill out the survey?

But based on your request, we'll use the employees in the table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeID FROM EmployeeData
```

Now we need to add in the possible questions.  For this you could use a temp table, but we'll just use a hard coded sql.

```
SELECT 1 AS Question UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3
```

Now we join them with no join condition.  This produces a table with EmployeeID and each of the 3 questions.  Now we can select from this table of all possibilities and find the ones that don't exist in EmployeeData.  For this we're going to do a bunch of table valued subqueries.

```
SELECT EQ.EmployeeID, EQ.Question
FROM (SELECT E.EmployeeID, Q.Question
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeID FROM EmployeeData) AS E
           INNER JOIN (SELECT 1 AS Question UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) AS Q ON (1=1) ) AS EQ
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Answer FROM EmployeeData WHERE EmployeeData.EmployeeID = EQ.EmployeeID AND EmployeeData.Question = EQ.Question)
```

You can also left outer join on employee data and check for null values rather than use a not exists clause.

```
SELECT EQ.EmployeeID, EQ.Question
FROM (SELECT E.EmployeeID, Q.Question
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeID FROM EmployeeData) AS E
           INNER JOIN (SELECT 1 AS Question UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) AS Q ON (1=1) ) AS EQ
     LEFT OUTER JOIN EmployeeData ON (EmployeeData.EmployeeID = EQ.EmployeeID AND EmployeeData.Question = EQ.Question)
WHERE EmployeeData.Answer IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work as well.

```
select distinct question into #temp from EmployeeData

select ed.employeeid, a.question
from EmployeeData ed
cross join #temp a
where not exist (select 1 from EmployeeData ed1 where ed1.employeeid=ed.employeeid and ed1.question=a.question)
```